# What is the maths name for a set which contains the Domain and Codomain of a function?

Tags: functions, terminology

Im interested in this so that I can name a type parameter in a program I'm writing.

There is function that that has three parameters.

$D$: Domain

$C$: Codomain

$X,$ where $D$ is a subset of $X$ and $C$ is a subset of $X$

What is the special name for $X$, if there is one at all?

This is interesting from a program security prespective as by setting $X$ we can constrain information to only flow within $X.$

Comment: I can't think of any name for $X$, but the whole structure sounds like a partial function from $X$ to itself, unless recording the codomain separate from the image is really important.

Comment: Sorry I new to this, could it be better to think of a name using terminology from Category theory, so instead of Domain and Codomain and X we have some special names for their equivalent in Category theory?

Comment: There isn't a special name for the set. You should probably call it something like `domain_and_codomain`.

Comment: @newlogic In Category Theory, "domain" and "codomain" are common, but you could also use "source" and "target" as in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category#OneCollectionOfMorphisms

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/120153/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3528869/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I felt this question was especially related related to both computer science and maths, also in general are the two subjects not moving closer together?